# jQuery address plugin - Restoring what middle click did?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mouseevent

One of my biggest pet peeves with websites is when some genius developer comes along and drops Javascript actions ontop of all the links, entirely obliterating the mouse's middle-click (default action in most browsers: open a new tab with that page). Today, I am that genius developer.

I'm using the [jQuery Address plugin from asual](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/), which does everything I need it to really well, with the exception of treating my middle click as open link in new tab. It treats the middle click as a normal click. I can still open links in a new tab, but I have to use the menu-click and select "open in new tab".

How should I fix this behavior? If I don't get my middle click back, my OCD is going to jump me in a dark ally somewhere, and this vein down the side of my forehead is going to keep growing and growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...OK wow. You really love that middle click feature, LOL.

You can try to override the plugin:

```
$('#target').mousedown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 2){
        //Middle button clicked!
        e.stopPropagation();
        return true;
    }
);
```

Or implement something similiar inside the original plugin's code.

Comment: This ends up binding two event listeners onto it, so I have the event to attempts to do it, and one that attempts to stop.

Comment: I did not understand that...?

Comment: I ended up forking the project on Github and just patching the plugin.,